# Is there a proof for $\neg\neg p\vdash p$ that doesn't use law of excluded middle?

Tags: propositional-calculus, alternative-proof, natural-deduction

I ask this because [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Double_Negation/Double_Negation_Elimination/Sequent_Form/Formulation_1) there's a proof for double negation elimination, problem is it uses law of excluded middle, and proofs for law of excluded middle use DNE/RAA themselves as I've seen which doesn't make sense!

Comment: LEM, DNE and RAA are equivalent: you can prove them from each other using intuitionistic logic. However, if you eliminate them all and use only intuitionistic logic, then you can't get LEM.

Comment: And you still have to specify the system you are using.

Comment: hmmm... interesting, and fun fact is I dunno the specific system I'm using as I said I've started to learn natural deduction from the internet :D

Comment: At least you can know if you're using intuitionstic logic or classical logic.

Comment: Classical one actually!

Comment: And which non-intuitionistic axiom do you have?

Comment: I dunno why we're going further, I guess you've already answered the question and that's they're equivalent!

Comment: As always, it all depends on what specific rules you are using. Some systems define $\neg$ Elim as going from $\neg \neg \phi$ to $\phi$

Comment: @KennyLau three axioms of classical logic: http://editthis.info/logic/The_Laws_of_Classical_Logic

Comment: @Pooria That doesn't even come close to the complexity of formal logic.